# react-highcharts: Cannot set property 'HighchartsAdapter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, browserify, react-highcharts

Trying to run next example http://kirjs.github.io/react-highcharts

Stuck with line:

```
global.HighchartsAdapter = require('exports?HighchartsAdapter!highcharts-standalone-adapter');
```

Without it, get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'HighchartsAdapter' of undefined
```

With it, obviously get

```
Cannot find module 'exports?HighchartsAdapter!highcharts-standalone-adapter'
```

So, the real question is how to include HighchartsAdapter.

P.S. The title of this question is different because it was my original google request. And I am not alone https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/search?q=Cannot+set+property+%27HighchartsAdapter%27+of+undefined&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Where is the full code to this strange example? `global` is a node thing, `window` is being assigned to it on the client which you are not doing hence the error (e.g. `window.global = window`). The require is using some special keyword too. Need the full source.

Comment: Source code for this example https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/blob/master/demo/src/index.jsx . Looks like it should be bundled using webpack, which I didn't touch before. I am trying to run it using npm.

Comment: Yep you can see in that webpack config in demo there that highcharts-standalone-adapter is an alias for "highcharts-standalone-adapter" : "highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework.src.js"

Comment: Looks like `exports?` is a webpack convention to add something to the global object https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#exporting. Perhaps webpack also handles the `global` var. You'll have to bundle your app using webpack with the same config (excluding the other demos) to get this closer to (or working)

Comment: Thx @DominicTobias for hint

Answer (score 0):

The original example should be bundled using webpack. Then I suppose it works fine.

If you want to use Browserify, then instead of using:

```
global.HighchartsAdapter = require('exports?HighchartsAdapter!highcharts-standalone-adapter');
var Highcharts = require("highcharts");
```

use next:

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts-browserify');
```